# Graphite query exclude items

Tags: ibm-cloud, graphite, grafana

Using Graphite in Grafna4, I need help with getting a query to select all records which does contain the word "deployment" in it, but doesn't contain the word "POD".

An example is attached (I would like to get the odd records in the example)

[image: Items list to exclude from]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [exclude](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.exclude):

`exclude(<your query>, "POD")`